# Why won't the height auto work on this one?

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to design a calculator that a guy made which is mostly written in Javascript. Trying to get the background grow with the content but, funny things happen.

1. when you press "load" button
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6v3Z.png
2. when you press "load" button again
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvvep.png

The whole code is in a div, how can the height jump to random places?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The images alone are not enough to explain the problem

Comment: I suspect you're dynamically showing and hiding content? That changes the overall size of your view. Please post some code.

Comment: Please update with some codes as well as explain better what you want and what you have tried??

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to do much without fully understanding the way in which you're applying your css here, or the way even in which you're adding your content to your red-background div.

But i'm going to assume a few things and work on those assumptions:

1. You are closing your divs correctly and are **appending** the desired extra content **inside** the div with the red background.
2. The desired content that gets outputted after the click is **floated**, so the div doesn't necessarily respond to the size increase because the content comes out of the document flow.

If such conditions just so happen to be met (there really could be a lot of solutions to this problem with the limited information you have provided). Then perhaps the **clearfix** (more semantically renamed **group**) class could solve your problem:

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

You can find more information about it here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/